# file upload with formData returns undefined file array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-data

im getting undefined from print_r($_POST), it's posting on the same php page.

```
Array ( [file] => undefined )
```

Edited - added part where it calls the upload_banner function

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="banner_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
  <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="filestyle" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var date = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName('note-editable')[0];

    if(date == "" || title == "") {
      alert("Please fill in the required fields");
      return false;
    }
    else {

        var cfm = confirm("Confirm Submit Changes?");
        if(cfm === true)
        {

          var editarea = content.innerHTML;

          $.post ("functions/add_upcoming.php",{date: date,title: title,sm_content: editarea},
            function(data) {
          });

          upload_banner();
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
  });




function upload_banner() {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#banner_form')[0]);
    form_data.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

      $.ajax({
        url: "upcomingevents.php?p=73",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form_data, 
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) { },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

json as datatype cause im returning arrays from php side, did not post additional code cause im already getting issue at the file upload part

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['file'])) {
  print_r($_POST);
  exit();
}
```

am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Are there any errors in your error.log?

Comment: there's no error but only undefined file array from $_POST

Comment: Where is `upload_banner` called? What is purpose of `form_data.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);`? Why do you set `dataType` to `"json"`?

Comment: We need to see where this `upload_banner` function is being called.

Comment: upload_banner is my form ID

Comment: Where is `upload_banner` function called? What is purpose of using `$.ajax()` to upload file?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but is your form ID not `banner_form`?

Comment: the code are too long stackoverflow wont let me post, let me re-editt

Comment: @Chris No need to show the entire JS document, just show us where it's called.

Comment: Why did you remove `upload_banner` function from Question?

Comment: cause i did a print_r if isset $_POST['file'] does it not ran the function already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're function isn't even being called considering you don't have the submit button for the handler to run.
It should be like:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="banner_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
  <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="filestyle" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png">
  <input type="submit" id="submit_btn"/>
</form>
```

Also you have a syntax error in your JS, there is no need for the second set of `});` to close the click handler.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sggf82am/2/

Comment: sorry for the confusion, yes i did removed the extra closing of the handler.

i have 2 forms are being submitted 
1) first on click of submit_btn, it'll submit the first form
2) once first form are done it will call the second function upload_banner to submit the second form which is the image upload


i have another file which has exactly the same code that was able to submit both without issues, the only difference is that the other page submits to other php file insteadof itself

Comment: not sure why but seems that it's not able to get the second form.. did changes to var form_data = new FormData($('#banner_form'));  and that works

Answer (score 1):

The FormData is set up incorrectly, should be :

```
var form_data = new FormData( );
form_data.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Are you sure the url refered by the ajax is correct?

Why is there query param (*`?p=73`*) as you're doing *post* and not *get*.

Finaly, try to print the response through

*`success: function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data))},`*

Comment: im still getting undefined for  file after changing the response to json

Comment: it responded  with {"file":"undefined"}

Comment: i do have the type defined in the input tag if u look behind if it after its name

Comment: How about try this `var form_data = new FormData( );` then `form_data.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);`